# MVC View Properties Dependent On Each Other

Tags: vb.net, model-view-controller

In my viewmodel, I have 3 properties: Start Date, Length in Years, End Date.

```
Public Property StartDate As DateTime
Public Property LengthInYears As Integer
Public Property EndDate As DateTime
```

The Start Date is manually specified in the view and so should the Length in Years. But what I want to happen is once you specify the LengthInyears, for the view to update the EndDate as you edit the field LengthInYears to the value StartDate.AddYears(LengthInYears). In my view, I have specified the fields:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.StartDate)
@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.LengthOfYear)
@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.EndDate)
```

I want the value to update during edit so when the changes are applied, the value is persisted on the post and I don't have to write anything in the action itself to update this.

I know it's possible to do this via JS / JQuery too, as I know how the fields are being rendered, but I want to avoid this solution, and if MVC can do this I will be very happy :)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You would still need javascript for this to update in real time with out a post back

Comment: Unfortunately I think you're correct. I've done a bit more digging, and this seems to be where frameworks like Angular.js and Knockout.js come into play. Thanks for replying.

Comment: Yep doing angular right now in MVC - this tut is good with MVC routes [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/806029/Getting-started-with-AngularJS-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Par)